# How is subscription being invoked?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service which contains the below:

```
  private menuBuilderCompleted: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});
  menuBuilderCompleted$ = this.menuBuilderCompleted.asObservable();
  menuBuildComplete(data) {
    this.menuBuilderCompleted.next(data);
  }
```

in a component I have the following subscription:

```
private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
```

and then listen using:

```
this.subscription.add(this.headerService.menuBuilderCompleted$.subscribe((data) => {
  this.wasInComponent = false;
}));
```

my question was, when I searched the source code in the solution I never see a call to menuBuildComplete, but if I add a debugger statement in the menuBuilderCompelted$.subscribe I see it hitting.  how is it getting called if I never called next?

Answer (score 3):

[BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) always emits at least one value.

```js
const a$ = new BehaviorSubject("Hello World");
a$.subscribe(value => console.log(value)); // prints "Hello World"
```

Comment: ahh ok that makes sense! so regardless it will emit something even if never called. A Subject would then only invoke if next is called, correct?  would not emit if next is not called like the BehaviorSubject is?

Comment: @Paritosh don't use a subject. A subject will lose the last emitted value if there is nothing subscribed. When you subscribe from a component you generally want to use either a BehaviorSubject for a default value, or a ReplaySubject(1) if the component needs to wait for values to be ready.

Comment: "it will emit something even if never called". It saves `this._value` internally and sets first value as what is passed as param to constructor. Every time a subscription occurs `this._value` is received by that subscription. So, it will emit current `this._value` to each subscription soon as a subscription is done. *Consider it as a Magazine subscription which would give you the latest edition even if you start the subscription way later after the publishing date.*

Answer (score 3):

As oposed to a Subject, a BehaviorSubject has a "starting" value (In this case it will be an empty object {}).
By setting this starting value, all subscribers to the BehaviorSubject will be notified of that starting value.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `BehaviorSubject` is initialized with an empty object, as a result the subscription is subscribing to that initialized value.

if you'll initialize it with a string for example `private menuBuilderCompleted: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject('hello world');`

then you'll see in the console `hello world` being printed